# Sup Norm of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

- The matrices the sup norm defined for $n$-tuples. That is, if $A$ is a matrix of size $n$ by $m$ with general entry $a_ij$, we define

$$\left |A\right |=\max\left\{\left|a_{ij}\right|; \text{i=1,2,...,n and j=1,...,m} \right\}$$.

**Question:** Let $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 1 & -3 \end{bmatrix}$ be a matrix. What is the $\left |A\right |$?

My answer is $3$,that is sup norm is maximum compenent of $A$ which is positive,right? Can you check? Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. It's clear that
$$
\vert A \vert = \max\{1,2,3 \} = 3.
$$